# BCrypt hash password in login url

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, bcrypt

My app uses a login/register system which encrypts password using BCrypt. When a users registers the password is encrypted using BCrypt and then stored in the mysql database. However when a user logins I want the password to be encrypted too for security reasons. I could encrypt the password before putting it in the login url, but you can compare 2 hashes so that isn't going to work.

How can I encrypt the password in the login request (url) too?

I didn't explain my question very well, so I will try to explain it in more detail. In the app I have a script that send an url request, for example site/login.php?username=name&password=password
When I look back my visitors logs on my cpanel I can read the &password field, so I know the password of my users. That's the thing I want to prevent, I want to make it so that even I can't see the users password anywhere

Comment: why you want to send password in url ?

Comment: *"However when a user logins I want the password to be encrypted too for security reasons"* - Umm... it's already hashed. Hashing and encryption are two different animals. Question's unclear, IMHO.

Comment: He meant to say: *He'd like to encrypt the Password the User enters on the Login form and then send this Password as a URL Parameter like: `login.php?u=username&p=encrypted_password`* And by the ways; @NorthSeaDevs why would you now want to send the Password in the URL Encrypted? You can Process / Authenticate the Login Credentials on the same Page and then simply **Redirect to another Page**: if need be.

Comment: @Poiz Who knows. Either way, the question's unclear and too broad also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Obviously (despite the palpable Danger of his approach; the OP is intent on simply submitting his Login Form via GET....  his form is probably using the "GET" method.... You are right with the point that **Hashing and encryption are two different animals** but still there could be no denying the obvious that he wants his form submitted via GET.... and is concerned that the password is showing up there in the address Bar.

Comment: The only sensible way is to use a an HTTPS connection.

Comment: @Poiz If they're using an SSL socket which they should, GET/POST doesn't matter.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep; that's what I said quite a few times already. ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, use HTTPS but if the password is sent in the URL it will probably be logged on the server which is a security issue, the password needs to be send in a POST via HTTPS.

Comment: @zaph I do Agree

Answer (score 1):

Send the password over a HTTPS connection and as a POST, not in the URL.

Using HTTPS will encrypt everything except the address portion of the URL.

The reason for using POST even when using HTTPS is because many servers log the URLs and that would usually include the password. Obviously  having the password in the server log is a security failure.

Don't hash the password prior to sending to the server, that just makes the hash the password.

Using `BCrypt` on the server to hash the password for storage is a secure method as is `password_hash` and `password_verify`, both common for PHP.

Answer (score -2):

I think  you are doing something wrong here by using the "GET" method in your login form instead of the "POST"

From w3schools :

> Never use GET to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL)

When you're sending the login details to a php page that will check the credentials, if your form uses [the POST method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp), the password will not appear in the url.

**EDIT :** Taking into account what was said in the comments, though it looks more secure and is recommended by W3 [(see Touheed Khan's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522167/3501368), POST **isn't** more secure than GET and, as [RiggsFolly said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522050/bcrypt-hash-password-in-login-url#comment74098377_43522161) :

> HTTPS is the only sensible secure mechanism

Comment: That isn't the reason not to use POST, someone can sniff a POST request just as easily as a GET request. The difference is that webservers won't log the contents of a POST request in the access log but they will log a GET request.

Comment: Plus, using GET/POST even with a plain text password in an SSL socket is just as safe.

Comment: @JamesHalsall Thanks, I wasn't aware both request types could be sniffed as easily !

Comment: Data in POST is **No More Secure** then it is in GET

Comment: HTTPS is the only sensible secure mechanism

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the input ! I was pretty sure I knew but it turned out I didn't ! I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ValentinPearce The reason for using POST even when using HTTPS is because many servers log the URLs and that would probably include the password. This current answer is so close to correct but just misses.